# Performance testing for Svelte applications

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, svelte, sveltekit

How can I do client side performance testing for Svelte applications?

Is there any similar kind in JMeter / WebLoad like true client protocol as in Load runner to test the Svelte applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TruClient protocol](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/tc/en/2021-2021_R2/Content/TruClient/TruClient_protocols.htm) is just a real browser (maybe [headless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser)) so it is not a "protocol".

- In order to test client-side performance you need a real browser -
- The most popular browser automation tool is [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/)
- JMeter can be integrated with Selenium using [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/)
- WebDriver Sampler can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)